# Unable to serve expressjs app from subfolder

Tags: express, nginx

I am new to express and nginx.

I have made a simple express app and configure nginx:

```
location /exapi {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8010;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

My expressjs app is:

```
    var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(8010, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8010!')
})
```

When I access my vps VPS_IP/exapi, I get response `Cannot GET /exapi`, but when I use `http://VPS_IP:8010` it is working as expected.

How can I access my express app from `VPS_IP/exapi`?

Comment: I have upvoted this as it is a generally clear and precise question. However if you can avoid txtspk in future questions it is appreciated - since effort in posts in fairly well mandatory here, readers appreciate the extra minimal effort in expanding `plz` into `please` etc. Thanks!

Comment: Try `location /exapi/` (with a trailing slash)

Answer (score 1):

Try rewrite in nginx:

```
location ~* ^/exapi {
    rewrite ^/exapi/(.*) /$1 break;
    subfilter /exapi /;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8010;
}
```